# What is a "reciprocal ordering" when discussing quasiprobability distributions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, notation, quantum-optics, quasiprobability-distributions

The Wikipedia page about the [optical equivalence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_equivalence_theorem) mentions that, if we denote with $f_{\Omega}(\hat a,\hat a^\dagger)$ an "*operator that is expressible as a power series in the creation and annihilation operators that satisfies the ordering $\Omega$*", then "*the quasiprobability distribution associated with $\Omega$ is given, then, at least formally [sic], by*"
$$\hat\rho = \int \frac{d^2\alpha}{\pi} f_{\overline\Omega}(\alpha,\alpha^*) |\alpha\rangle\!\langle\alpha|, $$
with $\overline\Omega$ the "*ordering reciprocal to $\Omega$*". There is no direct reference for this terminology. For what it's worth, that terminology seems to have been added in [this edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Optical_equivalence_theorem&diff=prev&oldid=497903544).

The above equation seems a bit confusing, but I'm assuming they meant it as a shorthand to write the following:
$$\operatorname{tr}(\hat \rho\cdot  g_\Omega(\hat a,\hat a^\dagger))=\int d^2\alpha\, f_{\overline\Omega}(\alpha,\alpha^*) g_\Omega(\alpha,\alpha^*).$$

What does "reciprocal ordering" mean in this context? Is it used/introduced in some books or papers on the subject?

Comment: Well, they illustrate it right below: when $\Omega$ is normal ordering, $\bar \Omega$ is anti normal ordering. "At least formally" probably indicates an elided "however hard or inadvisable it might be to compute in practice", no?

Comment: So you mean they meant $f_{\bar N}=P$ and $f_{\bar A}=Q$ then? what about symmetric ordering instead, would this be "self-reciprocal" in this sense? Also, is the equation right below correct? Shouldn't there be a $g_N$ on the RHS as well, for consistency with the previous equations?

Comment: Yes; symmetric ordering, Weyl ordering, is self-reciprocal, if you wish. Right, the density matrix is meant to be anti-normal ordered in this question... Gerry & Knight (3.105, 6) is friendlier.

Comment: @CosmasZachos upon having another read at Gerry&Knight, I guess I'd reformulate my question here as: is there anything to this way of writing things, and in particular this definition of "reciprocal ordering", aside a simple (and one could argue not particularly useful) mnemonic? As in, any deeper meaning to such "reciprocity relation" aside from one not wanting to write explicitly the three corresponding relations with $P,Q,W$ corresponding to $\Omega=N,A,W$?

Comment: Not aware of any hidden depth…

Comment: @CosmasZachos hidden depth aside, I wonder, is this terminology actually used somewhere outside of Wikipedia, that you know of?

Comment: Not that much of an expert to know. Might check Wolfgang Schleich’s book, which is far more thorough; perhaps pp333 et seq? Appendix J? Schleich emphasized how screwed up/singular  P is... Ulf Leonhardt walks around it, but does not go there. Perhaps Inspecting the oscillator might clarify things...